# Making text color lighter in a fedora terminal using a dark background

Tags: terminal, fedora, colors

In a fedora distribution, When you use a dark background, colored text are too dark to offer a good contrast. How do you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=239501), and the [easiest fix](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2004-07/5188.html) I found make one line :

```
cp /etc/DIR_COLORS ~/.dircolors
```